# how can copy file to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#

how can copy file to dictionary in c#

Comment: How should the result look like? A `Dictionary` is a collection of pairs of values, do you need a `(lineN number, text)` collection or anything else?

Comment: 14 questions, 0 accepts, goodbye.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you haven't specified the file format. If it's "key value", then you could do something like:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
var dictionary = lines.Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                      .ToDictionary(bits => bits[0],
                                    bits => bits[1]);
```

I don't actually like reading all the lines in at a time, mind you - it's fine if the file is small, but not nice if it's large. It's reasonably straightforward to write a method to read one line at a time:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerableLines(string file)
{
    using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust this for text encodings etc.

Now the query becomes:

```
var dictionary = EnumerableLines("file.txt")
                      .Select(line => line.Split(' '))
                      .ToDictionary(bits => bits[0],
                                    bits => bits[1]);
```