# Reading from an ini file with no Sections

Tags: vb.net, ini, read-write

I'm using a class similar to this one http://forgottencoders.co.uk/showthread.php?tid=53 but the ini file I'm trying to read from is in a different format.  For example it has no section headers at all and the settings are in the following format:

```
setting1 0
setting2 0
setting_this true
```

Is there a different way rather than an INI read/write class I can use to easily read/write to this type of INI file? I can think of a few ways like readline but that's a bit.. rough

Coding in VB.Net

Comment: If the settings are line by line like that, I'd probably opt for the `readline` method and then split the attribute and values by using a space as the delimiter.

Comment: Sounds good, can you think of any other ways I could go about reading and writing these settings?

Comment: You could read them into a `Dictionary`, although all values will have to be of the same structure. I'm not a VB dev, but Jon Skeet's answer here might trigger an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107390/how-can-copy-file-to-dictionary-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the settings you've shown is fairly straightforward and a `ReadLine` with a `String.Split` on a space will do (or will be what is happening at the lowest level).

However, are there settings with more (or less) than one "word" on the RHS (no harder because `String.Split` can stop at the first space)?

Are there blank lines or comments and what is the comment markers?

Comment: no blank lines, the file contains a setting name and value with only a space between them.  So a split on a space would work.